# Motion planning without a graph across an infinite plane

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, math, 2d, motion-planning

An object is positioned at **A** and wants to move to **B**. I want to calculate a movement vector there that doesn't move within the **distance D** of the to-be-avoided points in **array C**.

So if the move vector (B-A) normalized and multiplied with the objects speed would bring it within D of any point in C the vector is rotated so that it doesn't.

This is in two dimensions. Also, if this operation has a name, please make a comment or edit this question yourself as I had no idea of what to call it.

Also, my first instinct was to divide the active area into nodes and run a A* but I want to try the mathematical approach on this one, a few experiments with flocking gives me the impression that it can be done.

**Update** (from comments): This image is very close to the solution I want:

[image: Path]

Assuming we start at the point to the left, we start turning right towards the goal (the other point), we detect a wall on the right so we stop turning and move forward. The wall is gone so we are allowed to start turning towards the goal again, and so on. I know this may cause the object to not get there at all, but I want to define a **behavior**, not necessarily a **solution**, if you know what I mean.

**Update2**: Translating the active area into a set of nodes might prove inefficient. A* and other heuristic graph traversal algorithms are great for low dimensional problems. But the area I want to move across is infinite in size and only has a handful of obstacles scattered across it. The nodes themselves, or rather the potential positions, are infinitely small. This could of course be optimized with a quad tree of some sort but I have a feeling simple movement vectors that are in some way rotated and interpolated can solve this as well.

Comment: are you looking to find the minimum path that satisfies this criteria or any solution?

Comment: Any solution. Or rather, I'm not looking for a path at all. The object shouldn't "plan" its path, but instead it should only look one step ahead. Its not a robot planning its path, its more in line with flocking or cellular automata here. At least that's the effect I'm going for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also on the [page you linked to in your answer](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/) is a pretty good discussion of steering behaviours in general.

In particular, look at his pages for [containment](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/Containment.html) and [path following](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/PathFollow.html) for good examples.

[Steering Behaviors for Autonomous Characters](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/)

Answer (score 3):

I hear this called [motion planning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_planning), and pathfinding (as mentioned above)

There are a *lot* of algorithms, but from your description, a [visibility graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visibility_graph) might be a good start. You have a graph with points A, B, and polygons around each point in C (you could also do it with circles by calculating tangent lines from each point, I believe). You calculate edges as potential paths between the points. Here's a [slide show](https://noppa.tkk.fi/noppa/kurssi/maa-123.2340/materiaali/lecture_slides__lecture_4.pdf) which explains it better.

Then, on top of the visibilty graph, apply a search algorithm like A* (a heuristic search) to find the most optimal path through the graph.

However, you should consider what you are looking for. The above approach will find a shortest path by sticking extremely close to all corners, but other algorithms might better fit your idea of optimality.

Comment: The image "Example of valid path" in the "Motion planning" wiki article you posted is very close to the solution I want. Assuming we start at the point to the left, we start turning right towards the goal (the other point), we detect a wall on the right so we stop turning and move forward. The wall is gone so we start turning towards the goal again, and so on. I know this may cause the object to not get there at all, but I want to define a behavior, not a solution, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [potential fields](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1125.asp).  This offers a way to avoid "hugging the edges" of the obstacles.

But note that, like the A* algorithm, this requires that you quantize the state space, and may therefore be quite computationally intensive depending on how much accuracy you need.

Comment: The expensive computations is the very reason I want to avoid the A*. Also note that my world is changing rapidly, making the quantization of it virtually impossible. It was a good read though, sadly I think its hard to apply it to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quite verbose description of a flocking routine on [this page](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/).

Use the separation rule for all obstacles, and alignment only towards the goal position (since we have no flock mates) and (for the same reason) ignoring the cohesion rule.

I wounder if that would yield the desired effect.